# stackbar chart Dc.js - cant display top 10

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, dc.js

I've been trying to figure it out the pass days... I'm working on developing the stackbar chart using dc.js library. There are so many dimensions(x axis) that i need to display the top 10. I heard that in rowcharts, you can use the cap() but other charts dont. I'm trying to use .data(...) but I keep on getting errors. Even i did,

```
    chart.data(function(d) {
       return d.all();
    }
```

which is suppose to be the default but I receive the 
"Unable to get property 'data' of undefined or null reference" error in the dc.js library. I debugged it and i noticed in the dc.js, its getting undefined values. where i spot it in this function in the library.

```
function flattenStack() {
        var valueses = _chart.data().map(function (layer) { return layer.values; });
        return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], valueses);
    }
```

when i remove the .data(..) function, my stack bar chart works but its display alot of (xaxis or bars). Here is my code i worked on. I hope this helps.

```
//Create StackBar Chart
function createStackBarChart(parent, dimension, groupHelper, dataSet){

    var chart = (dataSet == 'default') ? dc.barChart(parent) : dc.barChart(parent, dataSet);

    var group1 = groupHelper.createGroup1(dimension, groupHelper.config);
    if (groupHelper.groupOrder) {
        group1.order(groupHelper.groupOrder);
    }

    var group2 = groupHelper.createGroup2(dimension, groupHelper.config);
    /*if (groupHelper.groupOrder) {
        group2.order(groupHelper.groupOrder);
    }*/


    chart._lookup = null; // stored lookup object
    chart.lookup = function(_) { if (!arguments.length) return this._lookup; this._lookup = _; };

        chart.width(900).height(300)
           .dimension(dimension)  
           .group(group1,  'A')  //remove_empty_bins(group1)
           .stack(group2, 'B')
           .valueAccessor(function(p){ 

               return p.value.items; })
           .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
           .renderLabel(true)
           .legend(dc.legend().x(100).y(0).horizontal(1).itemHeight(13).gap(6).legendWidth(400).itemWidth(100))
           .gap(5)
           .elasticX(true).elasticY(true)
           .yAxisLabel("count")
           .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
           .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
           .ordering(function(d) {
               return -d.value.items;
           });


/*         chart.data(function(d) {

               var getAllData = d.all();

               return getAllData;

           }); */


        chart.renderlet(function (chart) {
           // rotate x-axis labels
           chart.selectAll('g.x text')
             .attr('transform', 'translate(-10,10) rotate(315)');      
     });

        return chart;
    }
```

I also tried to use .ticks(10) but nothing happens. Please can you insist me? I'm using multiple charts. So i cannot filter the top 10 and display it in the stackbar charts. How to display the top 10 in the stackbar chart without forcing to filter the rest of the charts. I just want to display it and I'll figure out how to crossfilter it.

Comment: You're not imagining it, [`.data()` does not work as advertised](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/584) for many of the charts, because those charts already use the feature internally. Instead I would suggest using a [fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups) - there's one example [in this comment](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/237#issuecomment-272157974) and I think you will find other examples elsewhere.